# Install a 32-bit distro on WSL 2

Tags: linux, windows-10, virtual-machine, 32-bit, wsl2

I work on a Win10x64 PC and I need a native 32-bit Linux environment.
I try to do so in a WSL2 VM.

- I don't want to compile with `-m32` and then run a 32-bit binary on a 64-bit system.
- I want a VM where `getconf LONG_BIT` prints 32.
- I used to work with a Virtual PC's WM, but now I'd like to take advantage of WSL2.

One of my friends has a WSL2's "debian32" distro installed on his PC.
His distro is exactly what I need, but I can't find any trace of it on the net...

Does anyone know how and where to find a real 32-bit distro ready to be installed on WSL2 ?
(not necessarily a *debian*...)

Comment: You might be able to have 32-bit userspace, but since WSL distros shares one same kernel from Microsoft, it won't be 32-bit.

Comment: @TomYan You should make that an answer, because there's really nothing else to add.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

At last I solved my issue !
I ask to my friend to export his distro and then I imported it, and it works.
When I compile/run this code:

```c
#include <cstdio>

int main ()
    {
    printf("compil = %s\n",__TIME__ ) ;
    printf("size ptr   = %u\n",(int)sizeof( void* )) ;
    printf("size func  = %u\n",(int)sizeof( int(*)(int) )) ;
    printf("size long  = %u\n",(int)sizeof( long )) ;
    printf("size llong = %u\n",(int)sizeof( long long )) ;
    printf("size int   = %u\n",(int)sizeof( int )) ;
    }
```

like this `gcc test.cpp && ./a.out`
I get:

```
compil = 11:22:07
size ptr   = 4
size func  = 4
size long  = 4
size llong = 8
size int   = 4
```

And when I enter `getconf LONG_BIT`, I get 32.

I think this is the proof that my VM is 32 bits (so it is possible!)

Comment: Sorry to tell you, but this only proves you managed to run a 32-bit executable. You now have an “x32” userland. Check `uname -m`.

Comment: Thanks @DanielB , ```uname -m``` prints ```x86_64```. Does it means my system is actually 64 bits ? But then, how is it possible to "enter" in a "x32 userland". On a 64 bits Linux, I tried ```setarch -B``` or ```linux32```, but ```getconf LONG_BIT`` still prints 64.

Comment: As Tom Yan mentioned in his comment, WSL 2 will _always_ run a 64-bit kernel. However, this kernel can be used with a purely 32-bit userland, which is what you have now. Depending on your use case (which you do not describe in your question), that might be good enough.

Comment: Ok, I understand that I was wrong from the beginning, but I still don't know how to reach the "32-bit userland". Is there a way to switch in it from my native 64 bits environment ? Does it mean that at some point of the past of my debian32 VM, a comment was entered that switched into 32 bit ? Or maybe a config file ? Is any distro "turnable" into 32 bits userland ? I didn't find such command on the net... what ever I do on my other 64 bits distro, ```getconf LONG_BIT``` always prints 64.

Comment: @Captain'Flam it's really about the libc (and so on) used, if you are talking about "reproducing" / mimicking what happens in your "successful" WSL case. You can have a 32-bit container / chroot. Often distros would provide 32-bit libraries (and headers) as well, so you can even just install the necessary libraries and build a 32-bit program (which e.g., print out `sysconf(_SC_LONG_BIT)`)

Comment: printing `int` with `%u` invokes undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Though I've not tried doing so in Windows WSL, as you requestedm, it is easy to download and install a 32-bit OS in [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/).

As for source of Debian-based 32-bit Linux, try [Ubuntu 16.04](https://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/), either server or desktop.

Tushar Soam provides [step-by-step directions](https://medium.com/@tushar0618/install-ubuntu-16-04-lts-on-virtual-box-desktop-version-30dc6f1958d0) at